# Mechanical Advantage of Levers

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, distance

The mechanical advantage is given by MA = Load/Effort which is quite universal (at least in my short experience with them). However when i reviewed over the mechanical advantage of simple machines, especially levers , the formula for mechanical advantage stunned me, instead of

MA = Distance of Fulcrum to Load / Distance of Fulcrum to Effort

it was instead

MA = Distance of Fulcrum to Effort/ Distance of Fulcrum to Load

Does this not contradict what the MA formula is?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all starts from a consideration of work done by the effort (effort $(E)\;\times$ distance moved by effort $(e)$ ) and the work done on the load (load $(L)$ $\times$ distance moved by load ($l)$).

These two quantities are related by the efficiency of the machine

$\eta = \dfrac {\text{work done on load }}{\text{work done by effort} } = \dfrac{Ll}{Ee} = \dfrac{\left (\dfrac L E \right )}{\left (\dfrac e l \right )} = \dfrac {\text{mechanical advantage (MA)}}{\text{velocity ratio (VR)}}$

If the machine is perfectly efficient $\eta = 1$ then MA = VR.

In your example the ratios of the distances from the forces to the fulcrum is equal to the ratio of the distances moved by the forces.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doenst quite answer my question. Why is the formula for MA, Effort Distance/Load Distance instead of its reciprocal? Thank you for the answer but I still don't quite get it yet :(

Comment: Because when the system is 100% efficient load over effort (MA) is equal to distance moved by effort over distance moved by load (VR).  Then when considering levers distance moved by effort over distance moved by load is equal to effort to fulcrum distance over load to fulcrum distance.

Answer (score 2):

According to principle of moments(in levers)
anticlockwise moments =clockwise moments
Therefore

(Effort) *(Effort arm)= (Load)* (Load arm)
now

MA=(Load)/ (Effort)

(Load)/ (Effort)=(Effort arm)/(Load arm)

Therefore

MA=(Effort arm)/(Load arm)

Comment: Could you convert this to mathjax? A tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Consider defining variables and using them for the equations, rather than writing cumbersome, long names.